# Incidences between points and circles in the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Suppose we have $n$ points $P$ and $m$ circles $C$ in the plane. Let $I(P,C)=\{(p,c), p \in P, c \in C, p \in c\}.$ Then what do we know about 
$\max_{m,n} |I(P,C)|$?

Any references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe these are the best known upper and lower bounds, 
for $m$ points and $n$ circles [reversing the OP's notation to follow published convention],
established in the two cited papers:
$$
I(P,C) = O^*( m^\frac{2}{3} n^\frac{2}{3} + m^\frac{6}{11} n^\frac{9}{11}) + m + n)
$$
$$
I(P,C) = \Omega^*( m^\frac{2}{3} n^\frac{2}{3} + m + n)
$$
(where the $*$ hides logarithmic factors).

> Marcus, Adam, and Gábor Tardos. "Intersection reverse sequences and geometric applications." In *International Symposium on Graph Drawing*, pp. 349-359. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2004.
>
> Pach, János, and Micha Sharir. "Geometric incidences." *Contemporary Mathematics* 342 (2004): 185-224.

---

[image: CircsPts]

          

<sup>Figure from Pach, Sharir, "Geometric incidences."</sup>

---

Complexity results have been extended to $\mathbb{R}^3$:

> Sharir, Micha, Adam Sheffer, and Joshua Zahl. "Improved bounds for incidences between points and circles." *Combinatorics, Probability and Computing* 24, no. 3 (2015): 490-520. Preliminary [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0053).